# Malloc of string inside struct overflows

Tags: c, struct, malloc, address-sanitizer

The following code is a sample of the project I'm currently working on, coded in C.

I first malloc a struct, and then as an example malloc the string inside the first one. When I try to copy text from another string into it, and print it using the `printf` function, it overflows when I compile using `-fsanitize=address` as compilation flag.

I don't understand why though, as I think I'm allocating enough memory to the string given I'm just taking the length using `strlen` of the other one, with one additional character for the `\0`.

```c
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <string.h>

typedef struct s_word
{
    int     length;
    char    *str;
}                       t_word;

typedef struct s_list
{
    t_word  *word;
}                       t_list;

int main(void)
{
    int     i;
    char    *line = "this is a test";
    t_list  test;

    i = -1;
    test.word = malloc(sizeof(t_word) * 10);
    test.word[0].str = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(line) + 1));
    while (line[++i])
        test.word[0].str[i] = line[i];
    printf("%s\n", test.word[0].str);
    return (0);
}
```

```
=================================================================
==48531==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x00010940071f at pc 0x00010543ef60 bp 0x00016aee76a0 sp 0x00016aee6e28
READ of size 16 at 0x00010940071f thread T0
    #0 0x10543ef5c in printf_common(void*, char const*, char*)+0x750 (libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib:arm64e+0x1ef5c)
    #1 0x10543f7b8 in wrap_printf+0x78 (libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib:arm64e+0x1f7b8)
    #2 0x104f1bc64 in main+0x3ac (a.out:arm64+0x100003c64)
    #3 0x193291f30 in start+0x0 (libdyld.dylib:arm64e+0x16f30)

0x00010940071f is located 0 bytes to the right of 15-byte region [0x000109400710,0x00010940071f)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x10545fa6c in wrap_malloc+0x94 (libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib:arm64e+0x3fa6c)
    #1 0x104f1ba20 in main+0x168 (a.out:arm64+0x100003a20)
    #2 0x193291f30 in start+0x0 (libdyld.dylib:arm64e+0x16f30)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow (libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib:arm64e+0x1ef5c) in printf_common(void*, char const*, char*)+0x750
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0070212a0090: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0070212a00a0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0070212a00b0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0070212a00c0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0070212a00d0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
=>0x0070212a00e0: fa fa 00[07]fa fa 00 06 fa fa 00 00 fa fa 00 fa
  0x0070212a00f0: fa fa 00 00 fa fa fd fd fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0070212a0100: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0070212a0110: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0070212a0120: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0070212a0130: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
  Shadow gap:              cc
==48531==ABORTING
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The loop `while (line[++i])` is breaked when `line[++i]` becomes zero, so the terminating null-character is not copied to `test.word[0].str`. The copying should be like this:

```
do {
    ++i;
    test.word[0].str[i] = line[i];
} while (line[i]);
```

Another option is simply using `strcpy()`:

```
strcpy(test.word[0].str, line);
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it for me. Appreciate it.